# Error when trying to display member profiles

Tags: members

When I try to display a member's profile using the url:

```
http://coastsider.com/[member trigger]/[member number]
```

I get the following error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Member_settings::$config

Filename: member/mod.member_settings.php

Line Number: 370

Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in [home directory]/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member_settings.php on line 370
```

Interestingly, I get this message for every user *except* the Superadmin (user #1).

Comment: Have you checked the Member Group permissions for the Logged in member? Is the Member Account Privileges > Can view public profiles for the Member Group set to Yes?

Also verify the member group of the member id you're trying to access... is the user account banned?

Comment: Yes, the member can view public profiles. And, yes, I can't view accounts that have not been banned.

Comment: So when you click on the member's name from the memberlist you still get that error? Have you modified the profile templates at all?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error if I click from the member list.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed that might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that re-installing EE solved the problem.  I must have made a error when I did my last installation. The correct suggestion came form Kurt Deutscher on EE's Forums.

Thanks to everyone who asked the clarifying questions.